# inconsistent behavior of <iomanip>

Tags: c++, iomanip, setw

I have the following code

```
cout << setfill('0') << setw(4) << hex << 100 << 100 << std::endl;
```

The output is:

```
006464
```

If I want to let every number with width 4, I have to use

```
out << setfill('0') << setw(4) << hex << 100 << sew(4) << 100 << std::endl;
```

But if I want to print every number with hex and setfill('0'), I only need to set setfill('0') and std::hex once.

Does c++ design this on purpose?  what is its intention?

Comment: Some manipulators causes permanent state changes to the stream, some just for the next output.

Comment: `setw` only applies to the next operation. All other manipulators are permanent.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is on purpose. The stream operations are internally peppered with resets of the field width, specified by the standard. I think there's no good answer as to why.